# ACL to only output multicast traffic and allow IGMP messages back to router

Tags: cisco, acl

In the EDIT, I have created a set of ACL so that an interface on router 1 can only allow multicast packets out to router 2 and allow for any IGMP messages to come into the router 1. Is what I have done secure so that only traffic flows out of Router 1 and no one can hack into it and get onto Router 1 network?

So in detail:

Router 1 -> Router 2

Router 1 Interface (Outputting Multicast)
IP: 192.168.1.10
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Output multicast 239.0.1.1
PIM Dense Mode
Apply ACL here to only permit multicast under 239.0.1.1 and deny any traffic inbound to router.
Cisco 892, IOS 15.2

Router 2 Interface (Receiving Multicast)
IP: 192.168.1.20
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Receiving Multicast 239.0.1.1

**EDIT**: I have the following ACL set:

```
Permit IGMP Any Any
Permit PIM Any Any
Permit ip Host 239.0.1.1 Any
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your question is too broad. We need more details, for example, a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, then edit your question. Also, carefully consider that you may be asking an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/369973), where you are too focused on your perceived solution, and you should explain exactly what you are trying to acomplish.